# Unable to drop empty rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe `df` with **3 rows** where 3rd row consists of all empty strings. I am trying to `drop all the rows which has all the columns empty` but somehow the rows are not getting dropped. Below is my snippet.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, ''], 'col2': [3, 4, '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `NaN` values. You have `''`, which is not `NaN`. So:

```
df[df.ne('').any(1)]
```